# Get data from draggable into my droppable element jquery

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

Need help over how I can send/pass/retrieve data from my draggable element to my droppable element, or simply if someone can help me on how i can send my draggable back to its start position if it is not accepted by the droppable. Following is my dummy code which I'm trying.

```
$('#drag1').draggable();

$('#drop1').droppable({
    accept:"#drag1",
    drop:function (event,ui){}});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You will also want to review: https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Answer (score 0):

You can use draggable [revert](https://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-revert) and droppable [accept](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept) options.

```
$("#drag1").draggable({ 
    revert: 'invalid'
});

$("#drop1").droppable({
    accept: function(el) {
        /** Your logic goes here **/
        return el.hasClass('acceptable');
    }
});
```